# Java ArrayList concurrent modification

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm getting some problem to get this work well as i aspect:

```
    for(Iterator<Object> i = mylist.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Object obj = i.next();
        ArrayList<Object> newlist = new ArrayList<Object>();
        newlist.add(obj);
        i.remove();
        for(Iterator<Object> in = mylist.iterator(); in.hasNext();) {
            Object next = in.next();
            if (obj != next && (another condition)) {
                newlist.add(next);
                in.remove();
            }
        }
        if (newlist.size() > 2) anotheList.add(newlist);
        else for(Object r : newlist) {
            //mylist get back object:
            mylist.add(r);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get an elegant way to do that without copy mylist more and more times...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and why this code is not doing what you want it to?

Comment: This looks awful...  What are you trying to do?  I cant tell for sure, but it seems like you are trying to create a new list from some of the elements in the existing list, but this seems like a terrible way to do it.  Can you describe more about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I know, i had simplify my code to let it be more readable... What i need to do is making some list from one big list that remain only with discarded objects in it. Other lists that accomplish prerequisite are stored separatly in another object. Meanwhile big list has taken new objects to check in this function

Comment: So You want create list of removed objects from other list?

Comment: @Achilleterzo - sorry, but that attempted explanation is unintelligible too.  What is the first inner loop trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the code is currently doing is this:

- In the first iteration of the outer loop:

  - Remove the first element.
  - In the first inner loop, remove every other element that is not '==' to the first element (that we just removed)
  - If we removed more than 2 elements, put them all somewhere else.
  - Otherwise put the element back on the end of the list.

Obviously, this runs into a concurrent modification on the second iteration of the outer loop, because the inner loops have modified the collection that you are iterating in the outer loop.  You can't do that.

But, more importantly, the algorithm doesn't make much sense.  To my mind, that most likely means that the code is not doing what you intend it to do.  Unless you explain what you are actually *trying* to achieve, we can't figure out what the real problem is, and how to fix it.

---

I still don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve, but I think that the solution is going to involve one or both of the following:

- Change the implementation class of `myList` to one of the concurrent collection classes that *does* allow concurrent modification; e.g. `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.
- Replace the outer loop with this:

  ```
  while (!myList.isEmpty()) {
      Object obj = myList.remove(0);
      ...
  }
  ```

The latter remedy gets rid of the `ConcurrentModificationException` *provided that nothing else modifies the list while the first inner loop is running*.  The first remedy gets rid of the `ConcurrentModificationException` entirely, except that there is no guarantee that the first inner loop will see elements added elsewhere.

In either case, you have to worry about how to terminate the loop if it makes no progress in processing the entries.

The "big O" complexity is also a concern, but it is not possible to characterize without understanding what the "other condition" is doing.

Comment: Is like a card game, new list are games to play, others are cards in hand, but i realize that this can't work with another part of code, then i need to get back to my old code without removing the cards from the hand unless i play the game.

Comment: I can't use a while because "mylist" not get empty ever

Comment: @Achilleterzo - that's what I meant by the 2nd to last sentence.  There are ways to deal with that; e.g. by putting a marker object into the list.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you get a ConcurrentModificationException.

You can't modify the list in an iterator while a second one is iterating over it.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html